Dimensionality of Rank-4 Tensor defined in terms of rank-3 Levi-Civita Tensors
I'm working on a problem where I'm given a rank-4 tensor defined as:
$$ T_{ijk\ell} = \varepsilon_{ijp} \varepsilon_{k\ell q} S_{pq}, \hspace{3ex} S_{pq} = -T_{rqrp} $$
Since $ T $ is rank-4, I initially assumed I could have elements such as $ T_{1234} $. However, that would mean we would set $ \varepsilon_{k\ell q} = \varepsilon_{34q} $. So I guess my question is, if we're given a Levi-Civita Tensor $ \varepsilon_{ijk} $, does that mean $ i,j,k \in \{ 1, 2, 3 \} $, or is it possible for these indices take on higher values? The problem didn't specify the range of indices, so I'm unsure if I should assume the range is $ i = 1,2,3 $, or $ i = 1, \dots, n $.

The rank is completely unrelated to the range of the indices. The use of the Levi-Civita symbol suggests that the indices range over $1,2,3$.
